# Исключить столбец из JOIN

Tags: mysql, база-данных, запрос, join

Есть две таблицы. В первой хранятся данные, во второй хранятся атрибуты этих данных. 
В первой таблице есть столбец **attr_id** в котором хранится **id** записи во второй таблице.
При объединении мне нужно присоединить справа **все** столбцы второй таблицы исключив **id**.

Я бы мог перечислить все необходимые столбцы, но их может быть много со временем.

```
SELECT data.*, attributes.hidden, attributes.state 
FROM data 
RIGHT JOIN attributes 
ON attr_id = attributes.id 
WHERE (data.mark = '0')
```

Каким образом мне построить запрос к БД?

Comment: Ради собственного понимания, зачем исключать id? Если вы пытаетесь так оптимизировать скорость, то конкретно этот случай ничего вам не даст. Лучше построить составной индекс

Comment: В data тоже есть id.

Comment: Тогда используйте AS: `attributes.id AS attributes_id`, тогда в результате в `id` попадет `data.id`, а `attributes.id` => `attributes_id`. В этом заключалась ваша проблема?

Comment: @TotalPusher, да.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

К сожалению, в MySQL нет прямого способа исключить какую-то колонку из выдачи.

Один из воркэранудов, если брать чистый SQL — это получить все колонки таблицы из INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS, затем удалить оттуда ненужные и вставить получившийся список полей в SQL запрос.

Для запроса к одной таблице это будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT ', (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(COLUMN_NAME) FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_schema = '<>' AND table_name = 'data' AND column_name NOT IN ('attr_id')), ' from data');

PREPARE query1 FROM @sql;

EXECUTE query1;
```